# Python coverage does not redirect output to a file

Tags: python-3.x, windows, code-coverage, git-bash

I am trying to run coverage on a Python file of unit tests, WorkTest.py, and forward the output to a file, output.txt.

`$ coverage run --branch WorkTest.py > output.txt`

But, the output keeps appearing on the screen and there is no output.txt in the folder where I ran this command in. Why does coverage fail to redirect the output to the file?

I have Windows 10, python 3.6.8, coverage 5.1, and command line Git Bash that comes with Git.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if the output is not actually in the stderr instead of the stdout:

```
coverage run --branch WorkTest.py > output.txt 2>&1
```

The [Coverage.py command line usage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/cmd.html) does mention:

> The debug output goes to stderr, unless the `COVERAGE_DEBUG_FILE` environment variable names a different file, which will be appended to.